# Excel VBA conditional formatting - Removing formatting for 0 value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of values in a column, 1 NA 0 1 0 NA and 0.  I run a successful script on the column to highlight the top value in dark green, and the top 50% of values (excluding the top value) in light green.

```
Range("K4:K10").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.AddTop10
With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
   .TopBottom = xlTop10Top
   .Rank = 50
   .Percent = True
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
   .Color = 13434777
End With
Selection.FormatConditions.AddTop10

Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
   .TopBottom = xlTop10Top
   .Rank = 1
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
   .Color = 3394611
End With
```

That works, but what I want to now do (and this will be added to all columns, most of which have much higher numbers) is remove highlighting from any cell with the value of 0.  I tried the below code:

```
    Dim wsrng As Range
    For Each wsrng In Range("K4:K10")
        If wsrng.Value = 0 Then
            Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
        End If
    Next wsrng
```

But it is removing the highlighting from every cell in the column regardless of value.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change selection to wsrng.

```
Dim wsrng As Range
    For Each wsrng In Range("K4:K10")
        If wsrng.Value = 0 Then
            wsrng.FormatConditions.Delete
        End If
    Next wsrng
```

Comment: And should my first code be wrapped in this?  Or should this follow the code?